# Prolog weird Error When recursively iterating through a list

Tags: prolog

I need to make  a predicate that checks if the total cost of ingredients to make X equal Y. 
Here are my facts:

```
cost(carne_asada,3).
cost(lengua,2).
cost(birria,2).
cost(carnitas,2).
cost(adobado,2).
cost(al_pastor,2).
cost(guacamole,1).
cost(rice,1).
cost(beans,1).
cost(salsa,1).
cost(cheese,1).
cost(sour_cream,1).
cost(taco,1).
cost(tortilla,1).
cost(sopa,1).


ingredients(carnitas_taco, [taco,carnitas, salsa, guacamole]).
ingredients(birria_taco, [taco,birria, salsa, guacamole]).
ingredients(al_pastor_taco, [taco,al_pastor, salsa, guacamole, cheese]).
ingredients(guacamole_taco, [taco,guacamole, salsa,sour_cream]).
ingredients(al_pastor_burrito, [tortilla,al_pastor, salsa]).
ingredients(carne_asada_burrito, [tortilla,carne_asada, guacamole, rice, beans]).
ingredients(adobado_burrito, [tortilla,adobado, guacamole, rice, beans]).
ingredients(carnitas_sopa, [sopa,carnitas, guacamole, salsa,sour_cream]).
ingredients(lengua_sopa, [sopa,lengua,beans,sour_cream]).
ingredients(combo_plate, [al_pastor, carne_asada,rice, tortilla, beans, salsa, guacamole, cheese]).
ingredients(adobado_plate, [adobado, guacamole, rice, tortilla, beans, cheese]).
```

Here is my code:

```
helpt([],0).
helpt([H|T],V):-helpt(T,VT),cost(H,Y),V is VT+Y.
total_cost(X,K) :- ingredients(X,Y),helpt(Y,B),K==B.
```

This works correctly when I do these 2 things:

```
?- total_cost(carnitas_taco,3).
false

?- total_cost(X,5).
X = carnitas_taco ;
X = birria_taco ;
X = lengua_sopa ;
false
```

but when I do this:

```
?- total_cost(carnitas_taco,X).
```

it prints no even though it should be 5.

is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is imho

```
total_cost(X,K) :- ingredients(X,Y),helpt(Y,B),K==B.
```

if you change it to

```
total_cost(X,B) :- ingredients(X,Y),helpt(Y,B).
```

I get the right result.

`==/2` checks for equality, while you want to have unification.

Comment: why wouldnt equality work, I understand why yours works but why doesnt comparing the second arguments to helpt and total_cost work

Comment: because `X==2` evaluates false, because `X` is a variable and `2` is an atom. `X=2` however, would unify `X` with two and would work as well.